# Error al entrar en case ./cleaner.sh: línea 35: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `)'

Tags: bash

Estoy haciendo un programita en bash y me sale ese error. Todo funciona bien, menos al entrar al case en la opción 2
En la opción 2 le quité el ; pero igual da error

```
./cleaner.sh: línea 35: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `)'
./cleaner.sh: línea 35: `        2)  clear;'
```

```
case $teclaPresionada in
    1)  clear
        echo "Barriendo un poquito "
        autoclean
        waiting
        clear

    2)  clear;
        echo "Quitando basura "
        clean
        waiting
        clear

    *)  clear
        echo -e " Opción inválida. \n"
        sleep 2
        clear
esac
```

Y waiting es una funcion sencilla

```
function waiting {
echo -n "."; sleep 1;
echo -n "."; sleep 1;
echo -n "."; sleep 1
}
```

Comment: El último elemento de un `case` se ha de separar del siguiente `case` mediante `;;` (dos punto-y-coma seguidos).

Answer (score 0):

Debes cerrar cada posibilidad del `case` con `;;`:

```
case "$teclaPresionada" in
    1)  clear
        echo "Barriendo un poquito "
        autoclean
        waiting
        clear
        ;;

    2)  clear
        echo "Quitando basura "
        clean
        waiting
        clear
        ;;

    *)  clear
        echo -e " Opción inválida. \n"
        sleep 2
        clear
        ;;
esac
```

También te conviene ponerle comillas a `$teclaPresionada`.